# Make call to service on route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am aware that when you navigate to an identical path the component is not reloaded / `ngOnInit()` is not recalled (makes sense).

I have seen a bunch of SO answers which suggest subscribing to `activatedRoute.params` and then re-allocating data from a service as required. This is all well and good, but what is the recommended approach if **there is no url param or it does not change?**

```
{ path: 'screen/text/2', component: template.Template_Text_2_Text_Component },
```

In my case, the path represents a templated layout that can be navigated to  consecutively.

So what is the best method to trigger `this.courseService.getActiveScreen()` on navigate as currently the following does not work as there are no params...

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        () => this.screen = this.courseService.getActiveScreen()
    );
}
```

Comment: why would you navigate to the same route? what is the use case? I'd argue that whatever link or function navigates to the same route needs to call the courseService.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Well the component is populated with json data. so for instance, you might have the following 2 screens `{'text' : 'example1'}` and `{'text' : 'example2'}` but I want both of these to load into the same template, so they navigate to the same route. Yes you ar correct, each route must call the courseService.

Comment: Sorry I am still not following.. While I think this might not be a good use of routes, looking at the router service doc here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#events-anchor. You can subscribe to Router `events`. I believe it should be invoked even for same-route navigation. Give it a shot and let me know. I'd suggest you stay away from work arounds and use routers as explicitly  as possible.. makes for better code and less unpredictability :)

Comment: create a dummy route that just do redirectTo to you path and navigate always to this dummy route.